# { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED] code: 'ECONNREFUSED', errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect' }

Tags: node.js, sendmail

I am trying to send mail in node.js using express and i have used socket.io that is running on diff port, then this error message is coming.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    host: 'localhost',
    auth: {
        user: '____@gmail.com',
        pass: '*******'
    },
});

var mailOptions = {
        from: '____@gmail.com', // sender address
        to: 'vikash2696@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ', // Subject line
    };
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

Comment: give us some code examples

Comment: You need to Update the Post with Related Code ..

Comment: We can't give you any answer without looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    host: 'localhost',
    auth: {
        user: '____@gmail.com',
        pass: '*******'
    },
});

var mailOptions = {
        from: '____@gmail.com', // sender address
        to: 'vikash2696@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ', // Subject line
    };
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Vik, you need to add the code to the question, not to an answer.